# Confused about protractor v1.4.0 'protractor' and 'browser' global variables

Tags: variables, global, protractor, definition

The doc of protractor v1.4.0 (http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api-overview) tries to describe the global variables in protractor:

> `browser` - A wrapper around an instance of WebDriver, used for navigation and page-wide information. The browser.get method loads a page. Protractor expects Angular to be present on a page, so it will throw an error if the page it is attempting to load does not contain the Angular library. (If you need to interact with a non-Angular page, you may access the wrapped webdriver instance directly with browser.driver).
>
> `protractor` - The Protractor namespace which wraps the WebDriver namespace. Contains static variables and classes, such as protractor.Key which enumerates the codes for special keyboard signals.

My questions:

1) i don't actually understand these definitions and the difference between `browser` and `protractor`

2) in the definition of `browser` there is mentioned about `browser.driver` but when i look to the protractor API doc(http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) there is no `driver` property available for `browser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) There are 3 important keywords: `element`, `browser`, and `protractor`.

`element` is how you select content on the page, `browser` is how you interact with the browser that you're testing (i.e. `browser.get(...)`), `protractor` is a shortcut for you to access static variables defined in the `webdriver` namespace.

For example:

```
browser.get('http://www.someUrl.com'); // tell browser to go to an url
var input = element(by.css('#someInput')); // find the input using a css selector
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER); // Send a `webdriver` key to the element (see http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/enum_webdriver_Key.html)
```

I would suggest that you go through http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial as a starting place.

2) That's because `driver` is a property in `browser` and not a function. Use `browser.driver` to access the raw webdriver (although as a new user, you shouldn't have to use it)

Comment: please take a look to protractor v1.4.0 api page (http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api-overview). See the section in the left bar describing `by`. There is : `by - 
addLocator,
binding,
exactBinding,
model,
buttonText,
partialButtonText,
repeater,
cssContainingText,
options`.    I can't see `id` there though we can use `by.id` in protractor and that is very confusing. Overall Api page seems very bad. I can't figure out which things relate to what. Why the `id` property is missing under `by` api?

Comment: Sorry yes I left out `by`. `by` always goes along with `element` and is used as a selector (note my usage in the original example).

`by.id` is "http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.id". The reason it's not under the section 'by' but under the section 'webdriver.By' is because this is a locator exposed by webdriver instead of protractor.